# Cannot Install Node using NVM on my mac os mavericks

Tags: node.js, osx-mavericks, nvm

When I run the command:

```
nvm install 0.10
```

I get this error:

```
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '-xzf'
Binary download failed, trying source.
######################################################################## 100.0%
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '-xzf'
nvm: install v0.10.26 failed!
```

What should I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you find your answer?

If not, you can try:

```
$ nvm install -s 0.10
```

The `-s` flag is used to compile from source and it worked for me.

I also wrote a blog post about that, if it can be helpful :)

[Setting up nvm, node & npm on Mavericks](https://ladislas.detoldi.me/setting-up-nvm-node-npm-on-os-x-mavericks/)

Hope it helps! :)